# Testing method in UITabBarController sets title correctly

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest, xctestcase

I am currently trying to understand Unit Testing in Swift 4.
I have a class, with a method that setups my view controllers.

I would like to ensure that this method sets the title on the ViewController correctly.

However I cannot understand how to write this test?

This is my code and test so far.

Currently my tests fails with:

```
XCTAssertEqual failed: ("nil") is not equal to ("Optional("Favourites")") -
```

How is it possible to test this behaviour? Any help would be much appreciated.

**Controller**

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupTabBar()
        setupViewControllers()
    }

    // MARK:- Setup

    fileprivate func setupViewControllers() {
        viewControllers = [
            generateNavigationController(with: UIViewController(), title: "Favourites", image: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "favorites")),
            generateNavigationController(with: UIViewController(), title: "Search", image: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "search")),
            generateNavigationController(with: UIViewController(), title: "Downloads", image: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "downloads"))
        ]
    }

    fileprivate func setupTabBar() {
        tabBar.tintColor = .purple
    }

    // MARK:- Helpers

    fileprivate func generateNavigationController(with rootViewController: UIViewController, title: String, image: UIImage) -> UIViewController {

        let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)

        controller.tabBarItem.title = title
        controller.tabBarItem.image = image

        rootViewController.navigationItem.title = title
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        return controller
    }
}
```

**Tests**

```
import Foundation
import XCTest

@testable import Podcasts

class MainTabBarControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    func testTheInitialViewControllerShouldHaveTitleFoo() {
        let sut = MainTabBarController()

       let _ = sut.viewDidLoad()

        XCTAssertEqual(sut.navigationItem.title, "Favourites")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with accessing proper views in your code snippet. Btw I wrote an additional test for your tab bar controller, hope it will help :) Try this to pass the test:

```
class MainTabBarControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    func testFirstTabTitleIsCorrectAfterInitialSetup() {
        // Given
        let sut = MainTabBarController()

        // When
        sut.viewDidLoad()

        // Then
        let viewController = sut.viewControllers?.first
        let title = viewController?.tabBarItem.title
        XCTAssertEqual(title, "Favourites")
    }

    func testNavigationTitleIsCorrectAfterInitialSetup() {
        // Given
        let sut = MainTabBarController()

        // When
        sut.viewDidLoad()

        // Then
        let viewController = sut.viewControllers?.first as? UINavigationController
        let title = viewController?.viewControllers.first?.navigationItem.title
        XCTAssertEqual(title, "Favourites")
    }
}
```

It's good that you've already used Given-When-Then, but it would even great if you improve naming of the test. There are a lot of conventions, for example, I prefer something like *test_SubjectUnderTest_doSomething_whenConditionsAreCorrect*.

Here is another tip. Try to figure out how to separate the logic between view and view controller. It you get your hands dirty into at least MVP (Model-View-Presenter), then you'll figure out that its testability is better.

By the way, instead of this kind of tests it's more reasonable to consider *UI tests*. UI tests mostly rely on accessibility IDs. The most popular tools for test automation are Appium or XCUITests/Earlgrey if you prefer to go with native.

Comment: Thank you so, so, so much. You have helped me so much I really appreciate this

Comment: A couple of additional notes: 1) Instead of calling `sut.viewDidLoad()` directly, we can trigger the full loading mechanism with `sut.loadViewIfNeeded()`. 2) The comments are mislabeled. We start with Given (also known as Arrange). Then When (also known as Act). Finally Then (also known as Assert). So it's Given-When-Then not When-Given-Then. 3) Unit testing through the view controller is legitimate. UI tests are best kept to limited checking that things are wired up. This is the Test Pyramid: lots on the bottom, few on top.

Comment: @JonReid thanks that you noticed a Given-When-Then incorrect order, I just copy-pasted wrong comments! I edited my answer.
I agree with you on UI tests. Test Pyramid is the key idea.